# I have a differencing VHD that's eating away 90+% of my HDD. How can I shrink it?

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc, vhd

I have a differencing VHD that's eating away 90+% of my HDD. How can I shrink it?

The host OS is W7-64, the virtual is XP32.

Answer (score 2):

First, shutdown the VM, then you can compact it.  Go under the VHD editor under Settings and compact it.